# How to allow Linux PAM Authentication for non-Local users

Tags: linux, sftp, pam

I'm trying to implement a [SFTP server on Ubuntu](https://linuxhint.com/setup-sftp-server-ubuntu/) where the users should be authenticating via an external identity provider (they provide a REST API to validate user credentials).

I've done a POC using [pam_python](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pam-python) and able to intercept the password validation logic. But now it does not allow to login if the user is not already created locally.

```
Failed password for invalid user john from <ip> port 63159 ssh2
```

I did some research and the community seem to say that user should be created locally. (06 years old [ref](https://freeradius-users.freeradius.narkive.com/QD3iOM0Z/linux-pam-authentication-failed-non-local-users))

I'm trying to figure out if there is another way to get it done since it is not feasible to create all those users locally in my usecase.

**Update:**
I tried adding following code to create the user on the fly.

```
def pam_sm_authenticate(pamh, flags, argv):
  try:
    user = pamh.get_user(None)
  except pamh.exception as e:
    return e.pam_result
  
  home_dir = "/home/" + user
  if not os.path.exists(home_dir):
    os.system("useradd -m "+user+" -g sftp")
```

But it does not allow user to login in the same attempt and only allow if user tries to login again. Therefore, that is not user-friendly for my requirement.

```
sshd[8296]: Invalid user john3 from 192.168.1.1 port 64204

useradd[8299]: new user: name=john3, UID=1003, GID=1001, home=/home/john3, shell=/bin/sh, from=none
sshd[8296]: Failed password for invalid user john3 from 192.168.1.1 port 64204 ssh2
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is way more of a sysadmin question than a programming question. The fundamentals of it are that ssh requires that all user login attempts be mapped to a valid *user*. How that user _exists_ is irrelevant. I generally stack the authentication logic with a 'spoof user' name service switch facility using the same directory of usernames that comes from the authentication layer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @AnyaShenanigans, I just came through nsswitch.conf file. Do you have any suggestions to implement my own source for this?

Comment: You have a good question, but you have posted to the wrong StackEachange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). (you may also try [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/))

Comment: Thank you David for the reply. I've asked it here https://superuser.com/questions/1800121/how-to-allow-linux-pam-authentication-for-non-local-users

Comment: @JonnyMarotte Implementing an nss file for this is beyond the scope of a q&a site, and is documented [on the libc manual site](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Extending-NSS.html#Extending-NSS). There are several questions here related to it also if you get into trouble.